# Как обозначить, что вводимый текст является временем

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Суть задачи в том, что пользователь discord вводит некое число времени в формате HH:mm (допустим, 15:20). Далее в коде будет работа с этим временем, но оно не распознается как время, считывается просто как текст. Но нужно получить именно значения часа и минут, чтобы потом от них исчислять время работы.

```
   if (args[0] === "Время работы с:" && args[1]) {
      const timer = args[1];
      const fixTimer = new Date(fixTimer);
//эта часть кода не требуется, там все работает
 });
```

Comment: moment.js можно использовать

Comment: А можно полный код? Пользователь просто присылает в сообщении ТОЛЬКО время? Если да, то Попробуйте строку сплитовать по двоеточию и отдельно во время забивать часы и минуты.

Comment: да, она сплитуется, просто в дальнейшем к введенному пользователем времени будет плюсоваться 8, 12 и 14 в зависимости от дня недели. А так просто выводится: Время работы с: 15:20 - NaN:NaN, потому как не распознается, что введенная пользователем информация - это время

Answer (score 0):

Хороший вопрос. Можете использовать модуль moment :

```bash
npm i moment
```

Далее в коде:

```js
const moment = require("moment") // импортируем moment

const date = moment(your_date, "HH:MM") // вместо your_date поставь твой ввод из дискорда

const hours = date.format("HH") // получаем из даты часы
const minutes = date.format("MM") // получаем из даты минуты

console.log(hours, minutes)
```